# How to access a variable attached to the webpage using contentscript in - contentscript using Add-on builder

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script

I created an add-on using add-on builder. I attached a content-script to the `pageMod` in `main.js`

My content script counts the number of dynamic tags created using `document.createElement()`. This is done by creating a hook to document.createElement() and added this function to webpage by creating a script tag. My code is as follows.

**contentscriptFile:**

```js
addJS_Node ("var count=0;");
function LogDocCreateElement ()
{
    var oldDocumentCreateElement = document.createElement;   
    document.createElement = function(tagName)
    {
       var elem = oldDocumentCreateElement.apply (document, arguments);     
       console.log("Dynamically created a(n)", tagName);
       count++;     
       return elem;
    } 
}
addJS_Node (null, null, LogDocCreateElement);
function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
     var D                                   = document;
     var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
     scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
     if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
     if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
     if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';
     var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
     targ.appendChild (scriptNode);    
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {alert(count) }, false);
```

Now I am getting uncaught exception: `ReferenceError: count is not defined`.

How can I access this `count` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [the documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/access.html) on how content scripts access web pages - they don't see any custom properties and methods that the web page added to the DOM. In your case you would need to access the `count` variable via `unsafeWindow` object:

```js
unsafeWindow.count++;
```

However, as the documentation notes you should avoid using `unsafeWindow` if somehow possible. Here the obvious course of action would be to avoid creating the `count` variable in the page altogether. So instead of this:

```js
addJS_Node ("var count=0;");
```

You would just declare the variable:

```js
var count = 0;
```

But you would need to replace `unsafeWindow.document.createElement` rather than `document.createElement` in order for this change to be visible to the web page. Avoiding `unsafeWindow` here will be way more complicated, maybe you can use [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events) instead?

Comment: But the alert would display 0 if i declared as `var count=0`

Comment: @user1335906: That's correct - your `document.createElement` function is never called because the web page doesn't see it. See last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: where should i change the document.createElement whether in `LogDocCreateElement ()` or `addJSNOde()` sorry i didn't get you

Comment: can you please specify where should i modify

Comment: i included `unsafeWindow.count++;` in my code but i am getting 'unsafeWindow is not defined` error. How could i resolve this

Comment: I just tested, `unsafeWindow` is definitely defined as a global variable in the content scripts.

Comment: should i define the variable with `unsafeWindow` i mean `unsafeWindow.count=0`